# How to redirect from "page.php" to "#page.php" with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

My page runs on php for no js-users. For users with javascript on I load all content dynamic fromt the index in combination with the *hashchangevent*. So the links all look like www.page.com/#page.php, with a # before it. If the user types it in that way every thing works like charm and the content is being loaded over the index.php

But if a user would enter www.page.com/page.php the page of course ends up on the php page and the dynamic page will of course not work any more except the user will hit the index page and go on navigate from that. So that's not a cool way.

**My Question:**

How can I redirect user from:

> www.page.com/page.php

to

> www.page.com/#page.php

when they typed in www.page.com/page.php in the Browser

Of course only with javascript. The Page should work without javascript on normally with php.

Thank you.

Comment: What if someone with JavaScript enabled wants to share the page they're on with a friend who doesn't have JavaScript enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page loads, change the `window.location` to the desired URL by deconstructing and reassembling the URI.  Unfortunately, you'll have to include this on every page (i.e., `page.php`) on which you'd like the redirect to happen.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Insert the pathname after the hash, but skip the leading '`'
    window.location = "/#" + document.location.pathname.slice(1);
});
```

It's slightly less clean, but you could also remove the `window.location` bit from `.ready()` entirely.  This would effect an small performance improvement.

If you want the hash-redirect to affect only the last element of the current path, use the code below, instead.

```
window.location = "./#" + document.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

Comment: Very cool! Thanks! But what if my URL is longer, f.e. www.page.com/folder/page.php - or even more folder. What would I have to change? Cause now this moves the # to www.page.de/#folder/page.php.

Comment: Nothing.  The `Location.pathname` property captures everything that comes after the domain name and before the query string.

Comment: I am not certain I understand your question, but please see my amended answer as it may have the solution.